# how to disable network usage for other application in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, admin

i have bought new android 10 just some days ago . i was using android nought for a long time . i was looking in the setting and i found that i can restrict particular application for using mobile data .

i tried and turned off mobile data for many application and i found that , restricted apps were not able to access interent and my battery life has become much more longer .

i am android developer and i had created an application like Alarm manager which notifies user on battery charging on specific percentage than had added something like battery saver , which basically does nothign except showing ad. so i decided that how can i add this mobile data restriction feature to my app .

i tried to google it but found nothing , i guess i need to make my application Admin , i don't have much idea about admin but i know that i would be able to make as many changes as i want in my application .

is any body has idea what can i do in this situation . i have not seen any simliar app on play store as well . but it could be possible that i would have missed those apps .

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can toggle connectivity for other apps from your own app, doesn't seem like the system would allow that. You COULD look into a VPN app that can inspect network connectivity, and block requests from specific apps. But I'm not sure how much battery that would save you.

Comment: how can i acheive same thing with develeopeing VPN ?

Comment: I've not made a VPN app for android. You can check here, maybe it'll help you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

Comment: thank you for response but i have already check out VPN from google but again thank you